# Wheb Build pcl with visual studio 2010 I get point_types.hpp(1185): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'traits'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, point-cloud-library

I use PCL library with vs 2010. I don't use CMake and I include all dll,libs and include folders.

I wrote simple program to populate poitns cloud of hemisphere in PointCloud instance. Here is my super simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl\point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl\impl\point_types.hpp>
#include <cmath>

using namespace pcl;
void AddPointsToCloud(PointCloud<PointXYZRGB>& cloud);

int main ()
{
   PointCloud<PointXYZRGB> cloud;

   AddPointsToCloud(cloud);
   return 0;
}




void AddPointsToCloud(PointCloud<PointXYZRGB>& cloud)
{
    double R =2;
    int nTheta = 20; //number of grid points
    double dTheata =  0.5*M_PI / (nTheta - 1);

    int nPhi = 20;
    double dPhi =  2 * M_PI / (nPhi - 1);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < nTheta ; i++ )
    {
       for (int j = 0 ; j < nPhi ; j++)
       {
          double x = R * sin(i*dTheata) * cos(j* dPhi );
          double y = R * sin(i*dTheata) * sin(j* dPhi );
          double z = R * cos(i*dTheata);

          PointXYZRGB p;
          p.x = x;
          p.y = y;
          p.z = z;

          p.r = static_cast<uint8_t>(255 * x / R);
          p.g = static_cast<uint8_t>(255 *  y / R);
          p.b = static_cast<uint8_t>(255 * z / R);


          cloud.push_back(p);
      }
   }
 }
```

Now When I build within visual studio 2010 I get the following errors:

> Error 2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'traits'  c:\program         files (x86)\pcl 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl\impl\point_types.hpp   1185
>
> Error 3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files (x86)\pcl 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl\impl\point_types.hpp   1185
>
> Error 4   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files (x86)\pcl 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl\impl\point_types.hpp   1185

I don't understand why, I don't have any compile errors before building the project and everything is
correct in point_types.hpp (pcl header file)

please help me

Thank u in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to simplify your code to get an error. The below code induces an error with my compiler (which is GCC but the error is with the same declaration as yours - **traits**):

Did you try simplifying the code further?

```
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/impl/point_types.hpp>
int main ()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Have a look at examples that use point_types.hpp in PCL - there are none that use it directly. Instead, some other things are expected to be set up before it is included. See for example: [Adding your own custom PointT type](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/adding_custom_ptype.php)

The last code sample there instead contains the following include:

```
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
```

point_cloud.hpp is included via the following include in point_cloud.h (so does not need to be included in your application):

```
#include <pcl/impl/point_types.hpp>  // Include struct definitions
```

Comment: I see. I dropped #include <pcl/impl/point_types.hpp>  and now it build. Thank u